# JNDI name for EJB 3.1 running on JBoss 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss7.x, jndi, ejb-3.1

I'm trying to run this EJB example on JBoss 7 but it always throws NameNotFoundException.

The EJB that I try to test is: Calculator. When I deploy it on JBoss 7 show this next lines in the server console:

```
java:global/CalculadoraProject/Calculator!demo.CalculatorRemote
java:app/CalculadoraProject/Calculator!demo.CalculatorRemote
java:module/Calculator!demo.CalculatorRemote
java:jboss/exported/CalculadoraProject/Calculator!demo.CalculatorRemote
java:global/CalculadoraProject/Calculator
java:app/CalculadoraProject/Calculator
java:module/Calculator
```

The Calculator bean code is this:

```
package demo;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class Calculator implements CalculatorRemote
{
    @Override
    public double sum(double a, double b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

And the remote interface code is:

```
package demo;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface CalculatorRemote
{
    public double sum(double a,double b);
}
```

The main code which must connect the EJB through JNDI is:

```
package demo;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Context ctx=getInitialContext();

        String jndiName="?????????????";
        CalculatorRemote c = (CalculatorRemote)ctx.lookup(jndiName);

        System.out.println( c.sum(2,2) );
    }

    private static Context getInitialContext() throws Exception
    {
        Properties p=new Properties();
        p.put("java.naming.factory.initial","org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        p.put("java.naming.provider.url","remote://localhost:4447");

        return new InitialContext(p);
    }
}
```

First error is: Authentication failed. So, I create an "Management User" user for "ApplicationRealm" into the server: usr: test, pwd: test123 and then modify getInitialContext() to look like this:

```
Properties p=new Properties();        
p.put("java.naming.factory.initial","org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
p.put("java.naming.provider.url","remote://localhost:4447");
p.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"test");
p.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"test123");
```

The next error is: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ?????????????

So, I want ask: What name must I use to lookup my Calculator bean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) by using global JNDI name.

```
java:global/CalculadoraProject/Calculator!demo.CalculatorRemote
```

2) by using ejb JNDI name. Play with slashes a little if you still get the error. Should be correct if you have the required libs and don't have syntax errors in other places of code.

```
ejb:/CalculadoraProject/Calculator!demo.CalculatorRemote
```

JNDI structure 
For stateless beans:

```
ejb:<app-name>/<module-name>/<distinct-name>/<bean-name>!<fully-qualified-classname-of-the-remote-interface>
```

For stateful beans:

```
ejb:<app-name>/<module-name>/<distinct-name>/<bean-name>!<fully-qualified-classname-of-the-remote-interface>?stateful
```

Links worth reading:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project

Hope this helped :)

Comment: thanks for response. unfortunately none of the names you listed work. I also tried by adding this jboss-ejb-client.properties file in the client claspath:

`endpoint.name=client-endpoint
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
 
remote.connections=default
 
remote.connection.default.host=10.20.30.40
remote.connection.default.port = 4447
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
 
remote.connection.default.username=test
remote.connection.default.password=test123`

but still show the same: NameNotFoundException.

Comment: I remember having lots of problems with local clients and EJBs, thats why I started to use servlets to test them, if frontend is not ready yet. As you see, not everything might be included in JNDI name, so if, lets say, EJB doesn't have <distinct-name> it will look like this - ejb:/CalculadoraProject//Calculator!demo.CalculatorRemote. What are JNDI names you tried to use?

Comment: ejb:/CalculadoraProject//Calculator!demo.CalculatorRemote should work, if not, some configs are off or libraries are missing.

Comment: just now can try it without lucky...  Know you any way to manually assign the context/jndiName? So the EJB lookup just will require its custom name; like this: ctx.lookup("MyCustomEJBName") ?