# Failed to connect to EJB on JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x

Been helped through this uphill battle by some very smart Java and JBoss experts, and I appreciate it.  I finally got the EJBs to deploy on the new JBoss AS 7 without error.  Yah!  Now, however, I need to know the next step in addressing those beans from my application.  I have read a lot and found conflicting examples, unfortunately.  My code is thus:

```
DodsrUserSessionEJB o = ( DodsrUserSessionEJB) ctx.lookup("/dodsr/"+ejbName+"/remote");
```

This works on JBoss 6.  What should the new one look like to work on AS 7?

Perhaps I spoke too soon.  There are still 94 errors in the log file, many of which have the name "beans" in them, like remoting3-jboss-beans.xml.  Even though the log says that my EAR file was deployed could some or any of these error prevent me from connecting to them?

Comment: As the specification dictates it should be: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-intro004.htm

Comment: Note: I posted the wrong link as JBoss 7 implements the JEE6 specification; but luckily the specification regarding global bean naming hasn't changed.

Comment: I changed the call to this:
     DodsrUserSessionEJB o = ( DodsrUserSessionEJB) ctx.lookup("java:app/dodsr/" + ejbName + "/remote");
I am getting the cannot connect to the urls error (prodboxname:4447

Comment: Argh, sorry again, the specification documentation is really terribly unspecific I must admit. I must have had the JBoss documentation in my mind. The answer here has a better example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714648/jndi-name-for-ejb-3-1-running-on-jboss-7 . But that is not going to help you much as you seem to not even be able to connect to your server right now. That's another question entirely.

Comment: Those references don't help any.  I can ping the server but not through the code and connection.  I tired this too and got the same error:
DodsrUserSessionEJB o = ( DodsrUserSessionEJB) ctx.lookup("ejb:dodsr/" + ejbName + "/remote");

Comment: That's what I said, you have entirely different problems here than what you are asking. You first need to figure out what is wrong in your setup which is making the connection fail. Wrong host, wrong IP, server not actually running, firewall blocking stuff...

Comment: @Gimby I know the AS 7 server is running and I can connect because other applications are running and can connect to that server, specifically web applications, WAR stuff.  I am trying to connect through JDeveloper with my desktop application and trying to figure out what the call structure to any bean should be.  The admin of the server tells me he cannot run the JBoss admin tool because of vulnerabilities so the only way we can know if they are even running is to connect to them.  Sucks, I know.

Comment: @Gimby when I try to connect I get this error:
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls
my jndi properties file is pointing to the right server with port set to 4447.  Is this right?

Comment: SO is not a forum you know. Your question was about the correct lookup for EJBs, I'm sorry you ALSO have connectivity issues but that is off-topic. At this point the only thing I can assume is that either port 4447 is not correct or it is blocked by the network environment.

Comment: @Gimby - well it is still the same problem, I cannot connect to the server.  If you say that there must be a connectivity problem with the server then I will accept that, but how will I know if there is or not if I don't have the correct call to them, which was my original question?

Comment: I have given you plenty of suggestions to investigate, its up to you now to actually go do something. You'll have to go talk to your friend the administrator too I'm afraid, to ensure that there is nothing blocking you. Good luck.

Comment: @Gimby - thanks I will do my best.  At least post an answer so I can give you credit for the help you've offered.